# FullCalendar event title only allowed One Line

Tags: javascript, css, calendar, fullcalendar

How to make the event title in fullcalendar only **one line** even the title is long. By default, it is display full title, I wish to make it nice like Google Calendar.

Comment: I am refer this sample but no luck to modify its https://github.com/lyconic/fullcalendar.viewmore

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Look in your css file for the following entry:

```
.fc-event-time, .fc-event-title {
    padding: 0 1px;
}
```

and modify it like this

```
.fc-event-time, .fc-event-title {
    padding: 0 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fc-title {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: This just helps you for multi-line-titles. Sorry.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Still works in fullcalendar `4.3.1` I have another CSS page I use on the same page and just added it there, I didn't need to edit the Fullcalendar CSS

Answer (score 11):

Instead of editing the source CSS, you can do this on the HTML page:

```
<style>
.fc-day-grid-event > .fc-content {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
```

Source: [Multiline titles in fullcalendar ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27370044/194717)

Comment: You can also just add it to your own CSS file if you have one for the HTML page you're displaying the calendar on

Comment: Worked for me!  Please note .fc-day-grid-event is now .fc-daygrid-event.

Comment: Should be "nowrap" and not "normal"

Answer (score 0):

i am able to solve this with using white-space: nowrap;

Answer (score 0):

This is in the case that you are using the Angular 7 version 4 edition. This worked for me:

```
.fc-event {
    /* force events to be one-line tall */
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```