# Multiline titles in fullcalendar 2.1.0-beta1/2 in day grid

Tags: fullcalendar

I just upgraded fullcalendar in my project from 1.5.2 to 2.1.0-beta2. Since then my event titles are cut in the first line (overflow hidden) because of a new CSS style introduced here:

https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/commit/afe97d112a63c64f5e46a6ebfed144ccbf7a0a28

`.fc-day-grid-event > .fc-content { /* force events to be one-line tall */
    white-space: nowrap;`

Is there any reason why events are forced to be one line tall? If I don't want this, is it ok to just overwrite this style or will this lead to unpredictable behavior somewhere?
I couldn't find anything in the documentation nor using google.

Answer (score 18):

From https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1992

This is how to disable single line titles

```
.fc-day-grid-event > .fc-content {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: This is an old answer, but this still works in v3.1.0

Answer (score 3):

**In v4 and later**

```
.fc-event-main-frame {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

**Example**
[image]